# How best to organize data caching?

Tags: android, sqlite, caching

How best to organize the caching of html and images in terms of performance? Which is better: saving in files or using a SQLite database?
How do you do it in your applications? Cached data will be used when there is no Internet access.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: By default we have to maintain cache in HttpUrlConnection. So thats better to use.

Comment: You should not ask opinion-based questions here.